# Why is idiom "Reference to pointer" used besides programming style?

Tags: c++, reference

While going to some of C++ libraries, i came across programming style for passing parameters

```
void foo(Matrix*& input)
```

so my question is what does this idiom do, what purpose does reference to pointer serve?

Ignoring cv qualifiers, Matrix* and Matrix*& serve same. [i checked code is written by experienced guy from google in LLVM framework, hence just curious! ]

Comment: Look up the myriads of questions how to get the head pointer of a linked list implementation correctly initialized.

Comment: “Programming style” seems a poor reason to write the shown function like this. It could (and probably should) have equally well be declared as `Matrix * foo(Matrix *)`. Then, as a caller, I can decide whether I want to change the pointer in-place (`p = foo(p);` vs `foo(p);`) or not (`auto q = foo(p);` vs `auto q = p; foo(q);`).

Comment: @5gon12eder Depends, right? What if it's like `bool foo(Matrix*&)`?

Comment: @Barry True, but then it is a different question. The function shown above returns `void`. But even `bool foo(Matrix*&)` might better be `Matrix* foo(Matrix*)` (use `nullptr` as special value), `optional<Matrix*> foo(Matrix*)`, `std::pair<bool, Matrix*> foo(Matrix*)` or whatever is applicable to convey the required semantics.

Comment: _"Ignoring cv qualifiers, Matrix* and Matrix*& serve same"_ Not really..

Comment: @PreferenceBean can you explain?

Comment: @Mahesh: Look up "references" in your C++ book.

Comment: @PreferenceBean  yes indeed. "Matrix* and Matrix*& *serve* same" but "Matrix* and Matrix*&   *are not*  same". i hope this clears what i am asking for.

Comment: @Mahesh: How do they "serve same" if they are different? What does "serve same" actually mean? I'm not familiar with the phrase. I assumed you were trying to say that the two pieces of code are equivalent.

Comment: @PreferenceBean check out what Barry says in his ans. non-const Object of class Matrix when passed through pointer/ref allows modification to object state. he has used word serve too. If i may, question can be boiled down to " what is use case for using such reference to pointer?"

Comment: @Mahesh: The same as the use case for using a reference to _anything_? Yes, he used the word "serve", but he used it in a different context than you did.

Answer (score 3):

The same purpose that non-`const` reference to anything serves:

```
void foo(T& input) {
    // does something that modifies input
}

T val;
foo(val);
// now val is something else, potentially
```

Pointer is just another type. `foo` might need to change the value of the pointer (as opposed to what it points to), so it takes it by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to do a function which you pass it a pointer variable and it dynamically allocates an object and let the variable point to it. You have 2 options in this case. You either do:

```
void dynamicallyAllocateObject(Object **out)
{
  *out = new Object();
}
```

or

```
void dynamicallyAllocateObject(Object &* out)
{
  out = new Object(); // no need to dereference
}
```

You can't just let the function accept a pointer, or else the function will simply copy this pointer to the parameter variable and then store the pointer returned by `new` to this copy. For this reason, you will be needing a pointer of a pointer, or a reference to a pointer!

Answer (score 1):

In means that the original pointer passed to the function as the argument can be changed in the function and the changes shall be applied to the pointer.

If you want to change an object in a function you should pass it in by reference. A pointer is a kind of object.

Consider an example of creating a singly-linked list.

A function that adds new nodes to the list can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
};

void push_front( Node * &head, int value )
{
    head = new Node { value, head };
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = nullptr;

    std::cout << head << std::endl;

    push_front( head, 10 );

    std::cout << head << std::endl;

    //...
}
```

As the first parameter is declared like a reference then the original head of the list will be changed in the function.

If you remove reference then the original head will not be changed after calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are not magical. They are data like any other data. A reference to a pointer is just like a reference to any other data. There is no special idiom.

If you can fill the blank in this sentence

> A reference to type *X*
>   can be used for _____

regardless of what *X* is, then you know what references to pointers are good for.